# How to do date_range in reverse?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, dataframe

I'm dealing with problem how to create date range in reverse.
I'm trying this:

```
import pandas as pd
dates = pd.date_range(end='2/08/2014', periods=104, freq='W-Sat', closed = None)
```

Always i get from later to sooner like following:

```
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2012-02-18, ..., 2014-02-08]
Length: 104, Freq: W-SAT, Timezone: None
```

I want to range starting with '2014-02-08'.

Thanks

Solution:

Thanks for pointing out built-in reverse functionality, you need to go back and create DatetimeIndex to use it in Time Series like this:

```
dTmp = pd.date_range(end='2/08/2014', periods=104, freq='W-Sat', closed = None)
dates = [d for d in reversed(dTmp)]`
```

Answer (score 25):

Use could get this directly with fancy indexing:

`pandas.date_range(end='2/08/2014', periods=104, freq='W-Sat')[::-1]`

Comment: Efficient! Multi context!

Answer (score 9):

You can do this natively by specifying a negative frequency:

```
import pandas as pd
freq = '-1W-Sat'
dates = pd.date_range(start='2/08/2014', periods=104, freq=freq, closed = None)
```

note that the `start` parameter was used.

Comment: did not work for freq='-SMS' (worked with stated freq='-1W-Sat'); pandas==0.23.4

Comment: Worked for me for `freq='-3M'`

Answer (score 1):

use `reversed(dates)` instead of `dates.reverse()`